# Asp.net MVC DisplayTemplate Subfolders

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Simple question - is this allowed? if so, how do i do it?

As an example, say i have the following:

```
namespace Model.Event{
    public class Type1{

        [UIHint("Child")]
        public Child Child{ get; set; }

        [UIHint("AnotherClass")]
        public Model.Event.SubNameSpace.AnotherClass AnotherClass{ get; set; }

        [UIHint("Child")]
        Public Model.Event.SubNameSpace.Child Child2{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Child{
        public string SomeText{ get; set; }
    } 
}

namespace Model.Event.SubNameSpace{
    public class AnotherClass{
        public string SomeText2{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Child{
        public string SomeText2{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

and in the Views/Shared I have the following structure:

Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Model/Event/Type1.ascx

```
@Model Model.Event.Type1
    @DisplayFor(x=>x.Child)
    @DisplayFor(x=>x.AnotherClass)
    @DisplayFor(x=.x.Child2)
```

Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Model/Event/Child.ascx

```
@Model Model.Event.Child
    @DisplayFor(x=>x.SomeText)
```

Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Model/Event/SubNameSpace/AnotherClass.ascx

```
 @Model Model.Event.SubNameSpace.AnotherClass
    @DisplayFor(x=>x.SomeText2)
```

Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Model/Event/SubNameSpace/Child.ascx

```
 @Model Model.Event.SubNameSpace.Child
    @DisplayFor(x=>x.SomeText2)
```

I then create a ViewModel as:

```
public class MyViewModel(){
    [UIHint("Type1")]
    public Model.Event.Type1 {get; set; }
}
```

and then in the view I want to say

```
@Model Model.Event.Type1
    @DisplayFor(x=>x.Child)
```

I want it to then give me the Type1.ascx
and because of the UIHint attributes, give me the child views - does that make sense?

Comment: You want to pull controls from sub-folders?  Based on what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Look at `TemplateHelpers.modeViewPaths`. It's hard-coded and `static`.

However, you can have separate `DisplayTemplates` per controller.

On further thought, this does go through the view engine, so with spit and duct tape you might be able to make it work. Would be messy, though, since you don't get model metadata there.

Comment: why would they restrict being able to structure templates logically? that sucks :(

Comment: Well, no feature is free. Maybe they thought YAGNI? But you could request it for a future version.